# Tweet URL-link automatically converts into a clickable image

Tags: twitter, images

Under what circumstances do normal URL-links (without image upload) in a Tweet automatically convert into an autoexpanded image/link-combination?

For example: Links to some newspaper articles show as link only while others convert into some kind of clickable thumbnail of the article itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to a feature called [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview). After the site owner inserts [specific meta tags](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup) to the page and validates it via Twitter, a Twitter Card will be displayed in addition to the link. There are various [card types](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types) for different types of content.

Answer (score 1):

I made an app for this after getting frustrated that Twitter didn't do it automatically. If you're still trying to, you can just use `http://jpg.party/SOME_IMAGE_URL` and Twitter will make a card for you.

Comment: Really cool. Thanks! Do you know how to get an image url based on a keyword?

Comment: Looks like this web app is broken now :(