# Remove Preview Image when Posting a Link on Twitter

Tags: twitter, images

If I do a post on Twitter and include a link, a preview of this linked page shows as a preview image on the post. On Facebook you can just remove this using the dropdown menu of the post - I can't see how to do this on Twitter thought.  Is it not possible?

Comment: Explanation of this feature: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85277/159892 If you are owner of the website, you can try remove Twitter-specific metatags from webpage and try posting it again

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't appear as though you can do it from the web app. However, you *can* do it from the iOS and Android Twitter apps.

In each of those mobile apps, when you paste a link into a draft tweet, there will be an X in a black circle in the upper right corner of the preview. Click the X to remove the preview (but keep the link).

---

#### Android:

[image]

---

#### iOS:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just paste the link as normally you would do, and the preview image will have a button to close it in top left corner:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

this is clunky
in firefox, I add urlhere to the url
kinda stupid but it works

Comment: Hi ezra, I'm not really sure what you are replying to here.  Could you add more details to the answer to clarify?